# SQL Server & Mappoint/Spatial Table/Long&Lat

Tags: sql-server, spatial, mappoint

I am trying to map some data out of MS SQL Server 2008 (express) and Mappoint with the Mappoint addin for Sql server. The only issue i have is this spatial table stuff. I think i understand what a spatial data is now but i just need an example of how to go about cross referencing my states table with its spatial data. so i have a table with Vendor names, states they perform work in, type of work they do etc. States listed e.g (Florida, Montana, Puerto Rico, all 50 states) what is going to be their spatial reference. Or can i just add a Long and Lat to the table to reference the states. At this point i am giving up on the whole spatial table or query stuff. Can i just have a long and Lat colum in that table? Would Long&Lat be 2 in 2 different colums on the table?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you are trying to do - can you please restate. Give the overarching question you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth moving to full version of SQL Server with its geospatial extensions.

Or do as you suggest use data columns for longitude & latitude. Then you'd drop using the MapPoint add-in completely, and simply use MapPoint's Data Import Wizard. (you may need to create a udl connection to SQL Server).